# Jmeter : using the Regular Expression Extractor

Tags: java, jmeter

I'm using jmeter to test some web services.
I created four Thread groups that run consecutively.

In my second thread group, I have two web services :
The first one reads a CSV file and for each person ID it returns its name and first name :

```
...
<response>
   <name>Foo</name>
   <firstName>Bar</firstName>
</response>
...
```

The second one should take this couple of values and send them to another web service.
I read in the jMeter's documentation than the `Regular Expression Extractor` can do the job.

But how to tell him to get those values and feed the second ws call ?

Thank you,

Patrick.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to add two regular expression extractors as child nodes to the URL sampler, providing a reference name like `response_name`, an expression like `\<name\>([^<]+)` and a template $1$ (and another for firstname).

You can then use the JMeter variable `${response_name}` in another URL sampler to use the value captured in a request.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for simple jmeter regex extractor how to, see if this helps. http://goo.gl/TI9WW  To view the desktop sharing clearly, click on bottom right icon for full screen view.